# Ubuntu 16.04 Wireless Networking Troubles

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

extremely new to the Ubuntu scene, I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10 on Dual Boot. Laptop model is an HP Touchsmart 15.6" with AMD CPU/GPU, 8gigs of RAM, 750gb Hard Drive. I followed all the stuff I had to do to get it installed only to realize that my built-in Wireless adapter isn't working.
(For the specifics, f9j10ua#aba is the product number)

It recognizes my personal wifi spot, and lets me put in the password to it. Only issue is, that it doesn't connect to it. And instead the network manager seems to crash. Ethernet cable has had no problems thus far.

After a few hours of Question posts, and Google searches I came up with the following command/output.

**Command:** lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 **||**
**Output** network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
[Edited for less confusion]

I don't think it's a Broadcom at the least, but I'm not sure what else it could be. Went into BIOS and disabled Secure Boot, made sure the Networking was above the OS boot in the order. I haven't attempted just re-installing Ubuntu just yet in case anything went bad with the setup.

Comment: Are you running 3 different wireless adapters? If so, is there a reason?

Comment: Nope, just the Atheros AR9485 I believe, last I checked this laptop shouldn't have 3 of them.

Comment: If you're able to get to recovery mode from GRUB, do so, and select root from the menu, and enter the password, and at the prompt type: sudo fsck -f /, and lets see if you have some file/directory corruption. If it shows errors, run it again. Report back.

Comment: Alright, maybe something went wrong with the install, mostly because after the command and it finally did the error check it had 1 error. The error popped up for a second, only to then go back to the Recovery Menu and bug out on the screen, as in I can type, but black and white text show up all over the place if I do that.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to tell me, you were able to run fsck but it found errors, but then it filled the screen with what is called a kernel panic. Is this the first time you've seen that? A bigger problem than just a wireless problem. Sounds like it's time to reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. After a lot of browsing, i found a way to fix the issue. I am using HP Pavillion N15 with Mediatek 7630E wireless card in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Download this file:
https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/archive/release.zip

This is the driver that will be required. Extract the files in the download directory.

Open Terminal ( ctrl + alt + T)

Enter the following commands ( Please make sure you have extracted the files in the download folder. The name of the extracted folder should be "MT7630E-release"):

```
cd ~/Downloads/MT7630E-release
```

You should now see that the directory has changed.

Enter this command:

```
sudo make dkms
```

The driver package should be installed in a minute or two.

Reboot your system, and you should see that the wireless networks are now showing.

Hope this helps. :)